# google map. same map show different belong where from user visit

Tags: google-maps

i working with google map.
i put to iframe source link with variable q=Vilnius in my web page

```
src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=lt&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Vilnius&amp;aq=&amp;output=embed"
```

interesting thing happens when a visitor browsing from Lithuania, where the city is Vilnius, the map show well, but when a visitor browsing in the United Kingdom, the same map don't show well, show all island of Great Britains.Why does this happen? what need to do what to show right map of city?

Comment: I visited it form Italy and it showed me only the Vilnius city.

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off getting a link from google maps with a latitude and longitude in the the link. Try this:

1. Go to http://maps.google.com and find the place you want to show on your website.
2. Link the link-icon on the left side of the map and get the  code from there.

Notice that in the link you get, there's a few extra parameters, which define where the search is to be performed. Here's an example of such an URL: http://maps.google.dk/?ie=UTF8&ll=55.869147,11.228027&spn=7.563795,23.181152&t=h&z=6&output=embed - Notice the &ll and &spn parameters, which you don't have in your link :)

Hope this helps.